# Using code from views.py in javascript of html in django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am working on payment integration for my django website and in my views.py I have a function which checks whether the transaction was successful or not and I want to use that condition in my javascript so that I can save the details(shipping) that the user entered in the form if his transaction was successfully completed.
This is my views.py for checking if trans. was successful or not:

```
@csrf_exempt
def handlerequest(request):
    # paytm will send you post request here
    form = request.POST
    response_dict = {}
    for i in form.keys():
        response_dict[i] = form[i]
        if i == 'CHECKSUMHASH':
            checksum = form[i]

    verify = Checksum.verify_checksum(response_dict, MERCHANT_KEY, checksum)
    if verify:
        if response_dict['RESPCODE'] == '01':
            print('order successful')
        else:
            print('order was not successful because' + response_dict['RESPMSG'])
    return render(request, 'paymentstatus.html', {'response': response_dict})
```

and this is my javascript which automatically submits the details entered by the user when he clicks the payment button:

```
document.getElementById('payment-info').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      submitFormData()
    })

    function submitFormData() {
      console.log('Payment Button Clicked')
      var userFormData = {
        'name': null,
      }

      var shippingInfo = {
        'address': null,
      }

      shippingInfo.address = form.address.value
      userFormData.name=form.name.value

      var url = "/process_order/"
      fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({'form': userFormData, 'shipping': shippingInfo }),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) =>  {
          console.log('Success:', data);
          alert('Transaction Completed')
          window.location.href = "{% url 'index' %}"
        })

    }
```

I want to figure out a way so that I can call this submitFormData only when the below is true:

```
if response_dict['RESPCODE'] == '01':
            print('order successful')
```

(in my views.py)

Answer (score 0):

Your `paymentstatus.html` contains this JS code. correct? If so then you are already passing the `response_dict` for rendering in HTML. you should be able to condition the call of the JS code as per the value of 'RESPCODE'. It should be something like -

```
{% for obj in response %}
    {% if obj.RESPCODE == '01'}
        // call to your JS code
    {% else %}
        // something else
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The JS is in my checkout.html and not paymentstatus.html

Comment: Okay. then in the `<head>` section, you can include JS only when desired condition mets.

Comment: I have my js under the footer so can i use the above code that you wrote and at the place where you have written //call your jscode can i write submitFormData()

Comment: My submitFormData() function of JavaScript is in checkout page so how do i proceed with it?